# When is odata.stackexchange updated?

Tags: support, data-explorer, statistics

odata.stackexchange.com is damn funny. But when do cached(?) query results, like [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/89/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-for-each-tag), get updated?

Comment: Technically Odata is no longer offered but the update frequency went to weekly.

Answer (score 1):

The Stack Exchange Data Explorer is updated weekly, on Sunday at 03:00 UTC.

https://data.stackexchange.com/faq

You could use a [quick query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/12807/) to approximate when the last load happened (as of this post the 8th of January 2011)

Comment: hmm.. In this case, there could be something wrong with the query I pointed to. Of course I do not take notes, but I am pretty sure I had the same stats by Christmas...

Comment: @ran2 Bear in mind that the data could be up to 2 months out of date (the dump is of the previous month and could have been loaded up to a month ago)

Comment: thx Kragen, i tryin to be more patient ;)

Comment: The home page data.stackexchange.com tells you when the most recent data load was. matmematics is 1/12/2011 which is currently the most recent

Answer (score 1):

When SEDE is updated (other answers cover this), the query cache is dumped, so the first user to run a particular query after the update puts the new results into the cache.